# Android custom BaseAdapter getView() not called when scrolling down, items with different heights

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I'm using a custom BaseAdapter that fills a 5x3 GridView with items (ImageViews) with slightly different heights.
Scrolling up until some items (but not all in a row!) hides on top and then scrolling down, hidden items won't show anymore.
Tried with a Log in getView(), actually getView() is not called at all for those items, while i think it should be called.
Is this a GridView bug?
I'm working on both a real device KK4.4.2 and an emulator 5.1, same issue.

Here's some code:

```
public class GVAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private int columnWidth;
    private String uri[];

    public GVAdapter(Context context, String[] uri, int colWidth) {
        this.uri = uri;
        this.columnWidth=colWidth;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.v("GVAGETVIEW", "pos="+position+" String="+uri[position]);

        View gridView=null;

        if(convertView==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            gridView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_module, null);
        } else {
            gridView=convertView;
        }

        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.image_View_grid_item);

        float ratio=somecodeToGetAspectRatioFromUri(uri[position]);
        int columnHeight=(int)(columnWidth/ratio);
        Bitmap b=Bitmap.createBitmap(columnWidth, columnHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        b=someCodeToGetBitmapFromUri(uri[position]);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width=columnWidth;
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height=columnHeight;

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return uri[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Tried with `imageView.getLayoutParams().height=columnWidth;` (fixed heights), scroll seems to work fine, getView() is correctly called.

Also tried using ViewHolder with same results.

**EDIT 2**:
For now i ended up making all items the same height, sad workaround...

Comment: use view holder pattern first

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N you are right, but there's only one view, i think it's not a performance issue...

Comment: your loading from web right

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N no, actually i'm creating bitmaps drawing paths on their canvases. But i think it doesn't matters, getView is not called until the whole raw hides up or down. When it's called it works fine.